# Check whether a map contains all contents of another map

Tags: java, hashmap, contains

I am trying to check whether a map contains all contents of another map. For example, I have a `mapA` which is a `Map<String, List<String>>` and the elements are:

```
"1" -> ["a","b"]
"2" -> ["c","d"]
```

another `mapB` which is also a `Map<String, List<String>>`, the elements are:

```
"1" -> ["a"]
"2" -> ["c","d"],
```

I want to create a function `compare(mapA, mapB)` which will return false in this case.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Just for your future self's sanity, don't call it compare. You are not comparing. Call it something like `containsAll` or `subsumes`.

Answer (score 27):

Inside your `compare(mapA, mapB)` method, you can simply use:

```
return mapA.entrySet().containsAll(mapB.entrySet());
```

Comment: But will this also check for values? If no, what's a better way to check for both key and values?

Comment: @theprogrammer I'm not sure why I never responded to your comment, but yes, this will check for the existence of all entries in `mapB` within `mapA`. An entry consists of both a key and a value, and entry equality is determined by both the key being equal and the value being equal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

Assert.assertTrue(currentMap.entrySet().containsAll(expectedMap.entrySet()));

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Jacob G wont work in your case. It will work only if there is an extra (key, value) pair in `MapA`. like

```
MapA = {"1" -> ["a","b"] "2" -> ["c","d"] }
```

and

```
MapB = {"1" -> ["a","b"]  }.
```

What you need is this:

```
boolean isStrictlyDominate(LinkedHashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> firstMap, LinkedHashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> secondMap){
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> item : secondMap.entrySet()) {
        int secondMapKey = item.getKey();
        if(firstMap.containsKey(secondMapKey)) {
            HashSet<Integer> secondMapValue = item.getValue();
            HashSet<Integer> firstMapValue = firstMap.get(secondMapKey) ;
            if(!firstMapValue.containsAll(secondMapValue)) {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
    return !firstMap.equals(secondMap);
}
```

(if you do not want to check strict domination then just `return` true at last `return` statement)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
static boolean compare(Map<String, List<String>> mapA, Map<String, List<String>> mapB){
        return mapA.entrySet().containsAll(mapB.entrySet());
    }
```

As suppose, provided data is something like this:

```
            Map<String, List<String>> mapA = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, List<String>> mapB = new HashMap<>();

            mapA.put("1", Arrays.asList("a","b"));
            mapA.put("2", Arrays.asList("c","d"));

            mapB.put("1", Arrays.asList("a"));
            mapB.put("2", Arrays.asList("c", "d"));

            System.out.println(compare(mapA, mapB));
```

In this case ***`compare(mapA, mapB)`*** method will return false.
But suppose provided data is something like this:

```
            Map<String, List<String>> mapA = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, List<String>> mapB = new HashMap<>();

            mapA.put("1", Arrays.asList("a","b"));
            mapA.put("2", Arrays.asList("c","d"));

            mapB.put("1", Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
            mapB.put("2", Arrays.asList("c", "d"));

            System.out.println(compare(mapA, mapB));
```

In this case, ***`compare(mapA, mapB)`*** method, which I have written will return true.

***`compare(mapA, mapB)`*** method basically checking for all the entries in mapA with mapB, if same returning yes, else returning false;